# Google Cloud Vision AutoML poor prediction performance

Tags: cloud, vision, automl

I have trained a custom Google Cloud Vision model using AutoML. The purpose of this model is to classify a single label for a given image.

I have implemented a client to send HTTP prediction requests to their REST API. This works perfectly fine, however the time it takes to get a response is 13 seconds. This seems extremely slow and inefficient to me. I am sure that this is caused by Google, since I timed the method calls (uploading the raw image data could take some time, but using the same image on their pre-trained Cloud Vision network is a lot faster).

Did anyone else run into this problem and found a solution for this? Or is it better to just train my own model using Tensorflow/Pytorch with transfer leaning on e.g. Imagenet and build an API around that.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It takes 2050ms for me, I didn't find it bad. It would be better if you share the code for review here.